# How would I go about making input type color effect my canvas on code pen?

Tags: html, input

I'm trying to get

```
<input type="color" class="color1" id="color2"></div>
```

give an output of the chosen color, here:

```
let clothColors = [OutputNeedsToBeHere]
```

Currently, I have to Manually change the colors myself, by changing and adding color values

```
["Color","Color","Color"]
```

etc. I'm making a Tearing Cloth project for school and I want to make it have as much Customization as Possible.
currently this function changes the color via a Button accessing it via

```
onclick="colorChange()"

function colorChange() {
  cc += 1
  pattern = false
  if (cc >= clothColors.length) {cc = 0}
}
```

Now how would I get cc to become to output of the Color Input, so that I can simply choose a color on the

```
Input type="color"
```

and then click Ok and force it to change the color of the cloth manually to EXACTLY what I chose.

So Far I've tried making a Color-Wheel, and I guess my chrome version doesnt support them, or my Codepen Project is such a mess that it wont correctly activate, I also tried making an input text box that would change the color based on what you typed, (a Hex, RGBA, or Color). None of those worked, I did ask questions in a similar fashion to the one I'm typing right now, but those ones never obtained Full proof answers that successfully helped my issue.
[codepen][1] My full Codepen Project

```
<button onclick="colorChange()">BaseColors</button><input type="color" 
class="color1" id="color2"></div>
```

Partial Needed bits of Javascript:
cloth:

```
    function randint(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min
    }
    let accuracy = 10
    let gravity = 1000
    let wind = 0
    let cWind = 0
    let clothY = 40
    let clothX = 120
    let spacing = 4
    let tearDist = 60
    let friction = 0.99
    let bounce = 0.5
    let noTop = false
    let thickness = 1
    let clothColors = ["red", "orange", "Gold", "yellow", "lime", "green", 
    "blue", "purple", "black", "grey", "darkgrey", "silver", "lightgrey", 
    "white"]
    let cc = 0
    let pattern = false
```

Functions:

```
    function colorChange() {
      cc += 1
      pattern = false
      if (cc >= clothColors.length) {cc = 0}
    }
```

In the result I can Change the Color in a button by running the Length of the Colors written in

```
let clothColors:
```

and they are applied to the Moving cloth canvas. Unfortunately the Results I WANT are for the Colors Chosen in the input to Change the Color of the Canvas, See my link to the full project below if you wish to view the full code.

https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/ELwmoa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebXJaV

```
<button onclick="colorChange()">BaseColors</button>
<input onchange="colorChange()" type="color" class="color1" id="color2"></div>
```

```js
function colorChange() {
  var color = document.getElementById("color2").value;
  if (clothColors.indexOf(color) ==-1) {
    console.log("New color",color,clothColors)
    cc=clothColors.length-1; // prepare cc to be at end
    clothColors.push(color); // add new color at end
  }
  cc += 1; // business as usual
  pattern = false
  if (cc >= clothColors.length) {cc = 0}
}
```

Comment: You will need something like splice if you want to insert the new color where the cc is pointing

Comment: It's Definitely interesting... it looks actually not that hard now that I look at it. but it seems that I just didn't realize I could Add a new color to CC list every time a new color was chosen via the Input type.